# Is there a way to handle post request sent to frontend URL, but handle in expressjs server which on heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, server, react-router, server-side-rendering

I have problem, in my website when a user makes a payment, if the payment succeeds, the payment system will send me a post request to my **frontend_url/result** URL, but my server is expressjs and on another URL on heroku, so I need to handle in my backend that request which was sent to my frontend URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an asynchronous request to your backend to a different URL. It will depend on the kind of technology you are using on your front end application, you can do that with [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) or using a library like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). And then you would like to have a callback from your back end to your `frontend_url/result`

Comment: Thanks, but this is another problem, payment system can send data only to my frontedurl/result, but my frontend is served and hosted by github and backend hosted by heroku wit hanothre url...

Comment: Maybe I missed the point here. What I understand is, your payment system will send you a request to your `front_end/result` URL, and your back end is hosted on another server. If that's so, I think you can possibly manage this in two ways:
1. Set your payment system to send the request to your server application and from there you redirect to whatever front end page you like.
2. Send the request to the front end and do an asynchronous request to your back to manage the data you need.

Could you maybe provide more context about the technologies in order to help you more?